# Case Insensitive File name & Removing Directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am loading files to my server on a path similar to this
xyz.com/r/
Now i am going to share this URL with every user (of the particular file) for easy retrieval.so this URL needs to be case insensitive & easy to remember - something like this
xyz.com/filename

I have been able to hide the extension (.pdf) but 2 things still beat me
1) how to hide the directory in the middle 
2) how to make the file name case insensitive

To remove the extension, I am using this code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.pdf -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.pdf
```

I have tried the "CheckSpelling On" directive but it is not working for me.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To make the filenames case insensitive, you need to make sure mod_speling is on and you need this directive:

```
CheckSpelling On
```

To get rid of the `/r/` directory, try changing your rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/r/$1\.pdf -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /r/$1.pdf [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. The redirect part works. But it makes the actual URL invalid :) Incidentally, I found a code which solves my problem. 
RewriteCond $1 !^r/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /r/$1 [L]